# Compile errors when creating a basic Xamarin.Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to start developing with Xamarin. I am using follwing Visual Studio version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.5.2 (VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.2+27130.2010)
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02556

I create a new Xamarin project and get the errors below (without adding any code). I tried reinstalling Xamarin with no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  12  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  12  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  12  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  13  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  15  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  17  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  18  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  20  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  22  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  23  Active
Error   CS0012  The type 'AppCompatActivity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  23  Active
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)               
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 is not compatible with monoandroid60 (MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0). Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)             
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'App4.Droid.MainActivity' to 'Android.Content.Context'  App4.Android    C:\Users\thomaseg\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App4\App4\App4.Android\MainActivity.cs  22  Active
```

Comment: Did you try restore nuget packages for your project? What kind of Xamarin project are you creating?

Comment: Did you had a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47988647/xamarin-error-after-updating-visual-studio-2017-to-version-15-5-2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update all your packages? I got this error a while ago and updating them fixed it for me (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Updates, then Update all)